# How to prevent gcmTaskService periodicTask from running again if previous hasn't finished?

Tags: java, android

I have set up a periodicTask that runs every 60 seconds or so. It should only take a second or 2 to run, so it's very unlikely that any overlap would occur, but should the previous run hang or something, what would be the best way for me to detect this and skip the current run?

Also, would there be a way to kill the previous run from the new run? Or would I have to wait until the 3 minute timer runs out?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a way to make GcmTaskService thread safe?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in your service which is extending GcmTaskService, you must be using mandatory setTag() method which sets the tag in Task builder, whether it is an oneofftask or periodic task. 
Now according to official document,Tag is:

*String identifier for this task. Consecutive schedule calls for the same tag will update any preexisting task with the same tag.*

So if your onRunTask() method is taking 5 seconds to complete and you are scheduling the service to start in say 1 second , with the same tag, then it will be updated.
Refer: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/OneoffTask.Builder.html#inherited-field-summary

What you can do is make the onRunTask() method **thread-safe**. As according to:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmTaskService

*Bear in mind that your service may receive multiple calls from the scheduler at once (specifically if you've made multiple schedule requests that overlap). If this is the case, your implementation of onRunTask(com.google.android.gms.gcm.TaskParams) must be thread-safe.*

But like the case you mentioned, possibly overlap will not occur. But if you want to make it sure, then what you can do is use some kind of lock, which gets enabled when task is performing and put your logic in a condition which checks the status of the lock.

Now when you will be performing the task according to your logic, lock will be acquired, so condition will fail. And onRunTask() will return without performing your task. After your task gets completed, you release the lock and when periodically service runs again, condition will be true and your task will run again.

I hope this solves your doubt.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample implementation of makign onRunTask() thread safe? Thank you!